# How to change the database schema with Oracle Workspace Manager versioned tables

Tags: schema, oracle10g

We have an Oracle database that uses Oracle Workspace Manager (OWM) to version several of our tables. Currently we are supporting 4 workspaces in our system. We have now identified the need to change our database schema by introducing a new table to help create a level of abstraction. The current schema looks like the following:

```
       Table A ---- FK ----> Table B
           |
           |
            ------- FK ----> Table C
```

We want it to look like the following:

```
        Table A ------ FK ----> Table A' ----- FK ------> Table B
                                    |
                                    |
                                     ---------- FK ------> Table C
```

Table A is a version enabled table, while both Table B and C are not version enabled. We would like to keep Table B and C not-version enabled after the migration, and ideally Table A' would also not be version enabled. We would also like to have these foreign key columns to be non-nullable in their tables.

Any idea on how to accomplish this schema migration?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use OWM anyhow? There is little support for it and there aren't any serious projects that use OWM that I'm aware of. Good luck.